# How do I instantiate a property in a class where the property type is also a class?

Tags: c#

I have a class

```
public classs User
{
  public string Id {get; set;}
  public Details userdetails { get; set;}
}

public classs Details 
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Address { get; set;}
}
```

Now if i do the following

```
  User usr = new User();
  usr.userdetails.Name ="TestName";
```

It gives an error saying "userdetails" is null.
I thought it would have instantiated the sub class and in the quick watch I would be able to drill down and see te properties ?

Comment: _"I thought it would have instantiated the sub class"_ - What if you had `public class Node { public Node Next { get; set; } }`? Should `Node n = new Node();` also instantiate `n.Next`? What about `n.Next.Next` or `n.Next.Next.Next`? When should it stop? What if you run out of memory? What if `Node` takes a constructor argument? How would it know what value to pass?

Comment: I've edited your question title to something closer to what you're asking. If it doesn't match, please feel free to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instantiate it inside the `User` *constructor*:

```
public class User
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public Details userdetails { get; set;}

    public User() {
        this.userdetails = new Details();
    }
}
```

[Constructor MSDN documentation for your reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

EDIT:

Also as pointed out in the comments, there's a shorthand syntax for the above, which is this:

```
public class User
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public Details userdetails { get; set; } = new Details();
}
```

Comment: Or, more simply: `public class User { public string Id {get; set;} public Details userdetails {get; set;} = new Details(); }`.  You can simply initialize the property where you declare it

Comment: @Flydog57 ah yes - I forget about the "new" stuff :P I'll update my answer. THanks.